# rs.movenext does not work - run time error 3021

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, recordset

I try to crawl through all entries of my table "dbo.Bauteilspezifikation" and use the identifiers to call another function within a Do-Loop.

Hello together,
I use Access 2010 to get data from a SQL Server 2012. Here I try to check all entries of a table and modify them, if a certain date is overdue. 
The idea is to use the identifier "BauteilID" as variable for the function "Check_Freigabe". 
But after the first Loop, the recordset seems to be lost. This might be, because a new recordset is created within the function "Check_Freigabe".

I tried to create another recordset (rs2 in Addition to rs), but then, I get an error, where Access tells me, that the recordset is closed.

Any ideas?

```
Public Sub Update_Freigabe()
Dim stmt As String
Dim bt_id As Long

    stmt = " Select BauteilID from dbo.Bauteilspezifikation " & _
            " where gesperrt = '0' order by BauteilID asc; "
    'Debug.Print (stmt)
    getSelect (stmt)

    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF Or rs.BOF
        bt_id = rs(0)
        Call Check_Freigabe(bt_id)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub

Function getSelect(stmt As String)
    'Debug.Print stmt
    getConnection
    getRecordset
    Set rs = conn.Execute(stmt)
End Function
```

```
Public Function Check_Freigabe(id As Long)
Dim stmt, test, NewestDate As String

 stmt = " SELECT MBS.Stahlwerk, MBS.Freigabe, V.BauteilID, MAX(V.Datum) as NewestDate " & _
        " FROM dbo.MapBauteilStahlwerk as MBS INNER JOIN dbo.Verwendungsfreigabe as V ON MBS.BauteilID = V.BauteilID " & _
        " INNER JOIN dbo.Stahlwerkzeugnis AS SZ ON SZ.Stahlwerk = MBS.Stahlwerk AND V.StahlwerkID = SZ.StahlwerkID " & _
        " WHERE MBS.BauteilID = " & id & "  " & _
        " GROUP BY MBS.Stahlwerk, MBS.Freigabe, V.BauteilID "
    'Debug.Print (stmt)
    getSelect (stmt)

    If rs.EOF Or rs.BOF Then
        'MsgBox ("test")

        Exit Function
    Else
        If DateDiff("d", rs!NewestDate, Now) >= 365 And rs!Freigabe = "Frei" Then
            stmt_new = " INSERT into dbo.MapBauteilStahlwerk (BauteilID, Stahlwerk, Freigabe)" & _
                        " SELECT  BauteilID, Stahlwerk, 'Frei (> 12 Monate)'" & _
                        " FROM dbo.MapBauteilStahlwerk WHERE bauteilID = '" & id & "' and Stahlwerk = '" & rs!Stahlwerk & "';"
            'Debug.Print (stmt_new)
            insert (stmt_new)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

In each Loop, I want the to get the next bt_id, which I can use to call "Check_Freigabe"

Comment: Well, adjust your secret _Check_Freigabe_ to not manipulate or destroy your _rs_ recordset.

Comment: Can you post the code for `Check_Freigabe(bt_id)` it looks like you're using a recordset variable declared outside the Update function so you'll need to declare a second of a differing name, sometimes, just basic naming like `rstEmployees` and `rstDepratments` can help with things like this.  You can clone rs as soon as you have it to rs2 if needed, but not sure of what the function mentioned does.

Comment: added Function Check_Freigabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rs.MoveFirst { this makes it so that rs.BOF=True }
    Do Until rs.EOF Or rs.BOF { condition met, loop never runs }
```

Proper loop:

```
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    [Code]
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
```

Comment: That does not solve the issue in total. Is included my "check_Freigabe" function in the sub "Update_Freigabe" and created a 2nd recordset variable (rs2). I just cloned the "getselect" function for this purpose. Now I get error run time error 3704 (Operation is not allowed when the object is closed).

Comment: All you should need in the loop is `Call Check_Freigabe(rs!BauteilID)` assuming everything else is correct.

Comment: It also looks like you are missing `rs.MoveFirst` in your `Check_Freigabe` function. Other than that, I use DAO so I open and close recordsets differently than you. I can't tell if that part is correct or not.

Comment: Problem solved: I overlooked that my original rs was overwritten within myrs2-Function.